# XSD unable to validate XML containing dt:dt attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, xsd-validation

XSD file is unable to validate XML files containing `dt:dt` attribute. The `dt:dt` attribute is not accepted in XSD file.

For example.

```
<xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="optional"/>
```

In above xs:attribute , `dt:dt` name is not accepted. Hence XML files containing attribute `dt:dt="10"` is not able to be validated.

Is there a solution to modify XSD so that `dt:dt` attributes are validated?

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OperationalTopology xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"
                     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd.xsd">
   <Element1>
      <Element1_In ID="xx" dt:dt="string"/>
   </Element1>
</OperationalTopology>
```

XSD File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="OperationalTopology">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Element1" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Element1_In" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="ID" use="optional"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="dt" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In above the xsd gives error while validating XML.
The error occurs in dt:dt attribute.

Comment: Usually solution is to fix the code that generated the invalid xml.

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide the XML file and XSD file that you are working with, so that we can understand the issue and help you. Thanks!

Comment: @GhislainFourny I have pasted the XML and XSD file i am working with.

Comment: Thanks @MittalAnshul. I have adapted my answer to your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `name` attribute on the `xs:attribute` element has to be the local name only (`dt`). It should be declared in its own schema (say, `xsd2.xsd`) because it has a different namespace (unless this schema already exists somewhere of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <xs:attribute name="dt"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The original schema can then import the above schema, bind the namespace to the `dt` prefix, and use an attribute reference to `dt:dt` used instead of declaring it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" schemaLocation="xsd2.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="OperationalTopology">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Element1" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Element1_In" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ID" use="optional"/>
                                    <xs:attribute ref="dt:dt" use="optional" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I am sorry. I dont know how my question got editted. The attribute name is not "name" but the attribute name is dt:dt.                                                        e.g. <Element name="xxx" dt:dt="i4"></Element>. Please provide an answer for this.